# Floating point emulation or Fixed Point for numbers in a given range

Tags: c, floating-point, fixed-point

I have a co-processor which does not have floating point support. I tried to use 32 bit fix point, but it is unable to work on very small numbers. My numbers range from 1 to 1e-18. One way is to use floating point emulation, but it is too slow. Can we make it faster in this case where we know the numbers won't be greater than 1 and smaller than 1e-18. Or is there a way to make fix point work on very small numbers.

Comment: As usual, define the problem you're trying to solve. Give us the formula that you want to compute.

Comment: Calculations (multiplication, subtraction and addition) with numbers, where the initial, intermediate and final values are always within the range of 1e-18 to 1, that is never greater than 1 and never less than 1e-18.

Comment: What precision do you want?

Comment: You can place the point wherever you want in fixed point arithmetic. The only trick is that if the point is way out, as it would be in your case, it does not make sense to provide the standard multiplication or division—which would automatically produce results out of range. You can have constmul(a,b) and constdiv(a,b) instead, that return the fixed-point representation of a * b * const and a / (b * const), for a well-chosen const.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq - Yes I already had moved the point for my fix point calculations so that it works best for number less than 1, but 1e-18 is still too small to be represented in a 32 bit integer. And the problem with scaling like you mentioned would make numbers greater than 1, and we would again have to shift the point, so I don't think  it would work.

Comment: Your number system doesn't have to be linear. It could be log or sqrt based to cover the typical range. It all depends where you need the dynamics and accuracy -- and what operation dominates the calculation.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible for a 32-bit fixed-point encoding to represent numbers from 10<sup>–18</sup> to 1. This is immediately obvious from the fact that the span from 10<sup>-18</sup> is a ratio of 10<sup>18</sup>, but the non-zero encodings of a 32-bit integer span a ratio of less than 2<sup>32</sup>, which is much less than 10<sup>18</sup>. Therefore, no choice of scale for the fixed-point encoding will provide the desired span.

So a 32-bit fixed-point encoding will not work, and you must use some other technique.

In some applications, it may be suitable to use multiple fixed-point encodings. That is, various input values would be encoded with a fixed-point encoding but each with a scale suitable to it, and intermediate values and the outputs would also have customized scales. Obviously, this is possible only if suitable scales can be determined at design time. Otherwise, you should abandon 32-bit fixed-point encodings and consider alternatives.

Comment: He *could* use a fixed-point logarithmic number system, though addition in such systems is annoying.

Comment: 64-bit fixed-point arithmetic should work. In my experience LNS in software is only suitable when the computation has relatively few additions, and the accuracy requirement is fairly low, otherwise the tables needed for addition and subtraction become quite large which is often an issue for lower-end processors without FPUs (that also tend to have small caches). A reasonable starting point for looking into LNS is "FOCUS microcomputer number system", CACM, 1979.

Comment: @njuffa: It is not clear 64-bit fixed-point arithmetic would work because MetallicPriest has not yet answered questions about the precision required. 64 bits would have the span to represent the magnitude 1e-18, but it leaves little room for additional bits of precision.

Comment: Fair enough, note my use of the weasel word "should" :-). On the other hand I don't see that a categorical "fixed-point will not work" applies. Depending on the situation, fixed-point with some dynamic rescaling where operands are small could work. Of course the instances of rescaling should be relatively rare otherwise performance goes out the window.

Comment: @njuffa: I updated the answer to restrict it to 32-bit fixed-point. I wrote it in the context of the question’s ”I tried to use 32 bit fix point.”

Answer (score 1):

Will simplified 24-bit floating point be fast enough and accurate enough?:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#if UINT_MAX >= 0xFFFFFFFF
typedef unsigned myfloat;
#else
typedef unsigned long myfloat;
#endif

#define MF_EXP_BIAS 0x80

myfloat mfadd(myfloat a, myfloat b)
{
  unsigned ea = a >> 16, eb = b >> 16;
  if (ea > eb)
  {
    a &= 0xFFFF;
    b = (b & 0xFFFF) >> (ea - eb);
    if ((a += b) > 0xFFFF)
      a >>= 1, ++ea;
    return a | ((myfloat)ea << 16);
  }
  else if (eb > ea)
  {
    b &= 0xFFFF;
    a = (a & 0xFFFF) >> (eb - ea);
    if ((b += a) > 0xFFFF)
      b >>= 1, ++eb;
    return b | ((myfloat)eb << 16);
  }
  else
  {
    return (((a & 0xFFFF) + (b & 0xFFFF)) >> 1) | ((myfloat)++ea << 16);
  }
}

myfloat mfmul(myfloat a, myfloat b)
{
  unsigned ea = a >> 16, eb = b >> 16, e = ea + eb - MF_EXP_BIAS;
  myfloat p = ((a & 0xFFFF) * (b & 0xFFFF)) >> 16;
  return p | ((myfloat)e << 16);
}

myfloat double2mf(double x)
{
  myfloat f;
  unsigned e = MF_EXP_BIAS + 16;
  if (x <= 0)
    return 0;
  while (x < 0x8000)
    x *= 2, --e;
  while (x >= 0x10000)
    x /= 2, ++e;
  f = x;
  return f | ((myfloat)e << 16);
}

double mf2double(myfloat f)
{
  double x;
  unsigned e = (f >> 16) - 16;
  if ((f & 0xFFFF) == 0)
    return 0;
  x = f & 0xFFFF;
  while (e > MF_EXP_BIAS)
    x *= 2, --e;
  while (e < MF_EXP_BIAS)
    x /= 2, ++e;
  return x;
}

int main(void)
{
  double testConvData[] = { 1e-18, .25, 0.3333333, .5, 1, 2, 3.141593, 1e18 };
  unsigned i;
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(testConvData) / sizeof(testConvData[0]); i++)
    printf("%e -> 0x%06lX -> %e\n",
           testConvData[i],
           (unsigned long)double2mf(testConvData[i]),
           mf2double(double2mf(testConvData[i])));

  printf("300 * 5 = %e\n", mf2double(mfmul(double2mf(300),double2mf(5))));
  printf("500 + 3 = %e\n", mf2double(mfadd(double2mf(500),double2mf(3))));
  printf("1e18 * 1e-18 = %e\n", mf2double(mfmul(double2mf(1e18),double2mf(1e-18))));
  printf("1e-18 + 2e-18 = %e\n", mf2double(mfadd(double2mf(1e-18),double2mf(2e-18))));
  printf("1e-16 + 1e-18 = %e\n", mf2double(mfadd(double2mf(1e-16),double2mf(1e-18))));

  return 0;
}
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/HhRmUR)):

```
1.000000e-18 -> 0x459392 -> 9.999753e-19
2.500000e-01 -> 0x7F8000 -> 2.500000e-01
3.333333e-01 -> 0x7FAAAA -> 3.333282e-01
5.000000e-01 -> 0x808000 -> 5.000000e-01
1.000000e+00 -> 0x818000 -> 1.000000e+00
2.000000e+00 -> 0x828000 -> 2.000000e+00
3.141593e+00 -> 0x82C90F -> 3.141541e+00
1.000000e+18 -> 0xBCDE0B -> 9.999926e+17
300 * 5 = 1.500000e+03
500 + 3 = 5.030000e+02
1e18 * 1e-18 = 9.999390e-01
1e-18 + 2e-18 = 2.999926e-18
1e-16 + 1e-18 = 1.009985e-16
```

Subtraction is left as an exercise. Ditto for better conversion routines.

Answer (score 1):

Use 64 bit fixed point and be done with it.

Compared with 32 bit fixed point it will be four times slower for multiplication, but it will still be far more efficient than float emulation.

Answer (score 0):

In embedded systems I'd suggest using 16+32, 16+16, 8+16 or 8+24 bit *redundant* floating point representation, where each number is simply  M * 2^exp.

In this case you can choose to represent zero with both M=0 and exp=0; There are 16-32 representations for each power of 2 -- and that mainly makes *comparison* a bit harder than typically. Also one can postpone normalization e.g. after subtraction.